# What is wrong with this SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is wrong with below update query? it gives syntax error the error message is  as below:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Code:

```
UPDATE D_date a 
SET d_date_key = b.d_date_key,  
    full_date = b.full_date,    
    day_of_week = b.day_of_week,    
    day_of_week_display = b.day_of_week_display,    
    fiscal_day_number = b.fiscal_day_number 
FROM   
    dbo.[2017 Calendar update] b
WHERE  
    a.d_date_key = b.d_date_key;
```

Comment: The error is clearly saying  `Incorrect syntax near 'a'` with line no 1.

Comment: When asking questions like this, perhaps first ask/answer: Why did you think it **would** work? Based on some other SQL dialect, or random guessing, or what? But presumably not based on reading SQL Server's documentation about syntax, which would be the sensible place to look before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly aliases are not allowed in the `update` part of the `update` statement in SQL Server.  Instead just use the table name:

```
UPDATE D_date 
    SET d_date_key = b.d_date_key ,  
        full_date = b.full_date,  
        day_of_week = b.day_of_week,  
        day_of_week_display = b.day_of_week_display,  
        fiscal_day_number = b.fiscal_day_number   
    FROM  dbo.[2017 Calendar update] b
    WHERE D_date.d_date_key = b.d_date_key;
```

Or use an explicit `JOIN` and reasonable aliases:

```
UPDATE D_date 
    SET d_date_key = cu.d_date_key ,  
        full_date = cu.full_date,  
        day_of_week = cu.day_of_week,  
        day_of_week_display = cu.day_of_week_display,  
        fiscal_day_number = cu.fiscal_day_number   
    FROM D_date d JOIN
         dbo.[2017 Calendar update] cu
         ON d.d_date_key = cu.d_date_key;
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted it but it is corret, thanks.

Comment: @EricBrandt The second SQL that Gordan has provided does work. You can alias a table in the `FROM` but use it's actual name in the `UPDATE` clause. I believe, however, in T-SQL it's considered bad practice; I think in past versions it could cause odd behaviour; as the table named in the `UPDATE` clause might be treated as a different object to that referenced in the `FROM`. Much like if you had a clause like `FROM Table1 T1, Table1`. `Table1.Col1` would reference the second table. I *think* in older versions of SQL Server the same would happen (not so sure about more recent versions).

Comment: @Larnu . . . You *can* alias in the `FROM` and use the table name in the `UPDATE`.  The effect is a full Cartesian product, which is usually not what is desired.

Answer (score 6):

You don't alias the table you are updating in the `UPDATE` clause, you alias in the `FROM`. The correct syntax would be:

```
UPDATE a
SET d_date_key =b.d_date_key ,  
    full_date=b.full_date,  
    day_of_week=b.day_of_week,  
    day_of_week_display=b.day_of_week_display,  
    fiscal_day_number=b.fiscal_day_number   
FROM D_date a
     JOIN dbo.[2017 Calendar update] b ON a.d_date_key = b.d_date_key;
```

It's bad practice, however, to use aliases in ascending alphabetical characters (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`), or similar ideas (like `T1`,`T2`,`T3`, etc) as they're meaningless everyone. Use proper aliases. Such as `D` for `D_Date` and `CU` for `2017 Calendar update`.